# kubernetes ingress does not work! how can fix it?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm newbie to `kubernetes` so if anyone helped me I would appreciate. I create `ingress.yaml` file like following:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: backend-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: test-1.<domain-name>.me
      http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend-service
          port:
            number: 8000
```

then run the command `minikube addons enable ingress` and every things goes fine.
when I type the command `kubectl get ingress` I get this:

```
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS              ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
backend-ingress   <none>   test-1.<domain-name>.me   192.168.49.2   80      85m
```

the problem is that when I search the `test-1.<domain-name>.me` in my browser I get welcome page saying `wellcome to nginx`!

what shuold I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned any [annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#deployment), you have simply deployed an ingress which will have only a web page with “welcome ingress” will be deployed.

You need To deploy an ingress with the application url to work properly,

For Example :

The annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` will rewrite the target url  where the traffic must be redirected.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /something(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: http-svc
            port: 
              number: 80
```

In this ingress definition, any characters captured by (.*) will be assigned to the placeholder $2, which is then used as a parameter in the rewrite-target annotation.

For example, the ingress definition above will result in the following rewrites:

rewrite.bar.com/something rewrites to rewrite.bar.com/

Note: you need to configure your ingress with the correct host and path.

Refer to this official [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#terminology) which has detailed information of ingress, analyze and deploy with annotations.